# Jenkins pipeline dynamic choice parameter list for active checkboxes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job where I want to execute Selenium tests on multiple browsers depending on the user parameters selection. Currently I have an extended choice parameter with checkboxes:

```
 parameters{
  extendedChoice(defaultValue: 'Chrome', description: 'Tests will run at the default resoluton of 1024x768', descriptionPropertyValue: '', multiSelectDelimiter: ',', name: 'Browsers', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: 'Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge, Safari', visibleItemCount: 5)  }
```

What I want to do is also add a single choice selection for each checked browser, consisting of browser supported versions, basically sending a map of browser-version key/values. I tried also with Active choice parameters but with no luck.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNwM8.jpg